# Common functions in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, global

I am new to CodeIgniter.

I am using HMVC in CodeIgniter and want to use a module function in many other modules:

e.g I have a Locaton_model with function get_locations($param) { return; }

How do I use the above function in many other modules? Should I load the model in other module controllers every time I need this function or define the function some where globally?

Comment: put it in the helper folder and load it

Comment: no I can not add this in  helpers as I have many functions like this in my application. like departments, scores, country, abbreviations etc. The above are used as dropdowns in many module forms

Comment: You don't use helpers for that. Helpers are meant to be functions as "convertArrayToSTring()"

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that by using core controllers:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Instead of beginning your model with:

```
class Some_model extends CI_Model {}
```

You start with:

```
class Some_model extends MY_Model {}
```

Edit:
It is also possible to use libraries:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

This is useful when you want more general things, like a search engine, a IMAP interface, that kind of stuff.

Comment: I have two functions get_departments() and get_locations in two models/Modules. Now I am adding a user profile where I need dropdown of department and location. How do I call the 2 models to get the list of department and locations?

Comment: You can't. In PHP it is not possible to extend multiple classes. If you want to use the function in (almost) every class, you create one single core controller. If it is very specific, you might want to use a library.
Note that core classes can extend other core classes.

Answer (score 0):

if your creating your own model first make sure it is inside the core folder second on your controller extends the model name like this

`class myController extends Locaton_model
{`

```
function index()
{
$this->load->model->("your model name");
$this->yourmodelname->functionname($param);
}
```

`}`