# common controller functions in a codeigniter module

Tags: php, codeigniter, code-reuse

I am new to codeigniter and developing my first project with HMVC.

I have a module called exams in which I have many controllers like :

1. application/modules/exams/controllers/scale
2. application/modules/exams/controllers/result
3. application/modules/exams/controllers/questions
4. application/modules/exams/controllers/abbreviations

In the above four controllers I have some functions which I have used in all the controllers. How do I define a common controller for this module and place the common functions in that controller and extend in above four controllers.

One way of doing this is adding a common controller in

> application/modules/exams/controllers/common
>
> Common extends CI_Controller { .....

then extending this controller in my other controllers like:

> application/modules/exams/controllers/scale
>
> require_once('common.php'); class Scale extends Common {

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Again, use core controllers. See your other question: 
[Common functions in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886716/common-functions-in-codeignitor)

Instead of extending your model, you extend your controller. You can easily achieve that by using core controllers: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Instead of beginning your model with:

```
class Some_model extends CI_Model {}
```

You start with:

```
class Some_model extends MY_Model {}
```

You don't use require(), CI handles that for you.